# why only debian return 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, dns

i create a part of code that get local host and currently ip address , i try this on windows , linux(`opensuse` , `debian` ) , mac , and every one return his ip address except debian that return `127.0.0.1` and i am  connected to internet .

because i expect the following addresses

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

any help .

my code is writing in java and tested on different platforms .

i ceraet the code using `inetaddress` class in java

EDIt :

sbin/ipconfig OUTPU

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:33:e0:56:af  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:33ff:fee0:56af/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8705530 (8.3 MiB)  TX bytes:1857590 (1.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fc600000-fc620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22696 (22.1 KiB)  TX bytes:22696 (22.1 KiB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.68.1  Bcast:192.168.68.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:172.16.79.1  Bcast:172.16.79.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:1a:04:a5:86:5a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

etc/host

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 debiam.domain debiam

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

about src code it's just `inetaddress`

Comment: What if the system has multiple network interfaces (cards)? What if an interface has multiple IP addresses assigned to it?

Comment: but i run debian and opensuse and mac in the same machine all return the ideress correctly expect debian

Comment: You still haven't answer my question. Also how does you program work? Some source code would be nice.

Comment: send output of /sbin/ifconfig and also check /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact implementation, it will depend upon the interface you're checking in linux.  the lo interface will give you 127.0.0.1.  You probably have an interface like 'eth0' or 'eth3' that uses your expected IP address.

Answer (score 1):

by this commend in linux

```
ifconfig
```

you give this details

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx  
      inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::1e6f:65ff:fed5:8a16/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3363918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1892239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4890880074 (4.8 GB)  TX bytes:150386146 (150.3 MB)
      Interrupt:43 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:160038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:160038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:64218501 (64.2 MB)  TX bytes:64218501 (64.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

ip 127.0.0.1 is in lo(loopback , localhost) interface ,but in another interface for example eth0 your ip is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or ipv6 .